# VBA - Copy pasting across visible columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that imports a table and then goes on to hide columns that are not relevant to the end user.

As part of the formatting process, I need to add a header to the excel doc that consists of merged and unmerged cells.

My problem is that considering the fact that a number of columns have been hidden, it is proving impossible to import the header. The header would need to be pasted across numerous non-sequential columns. Is there a way to do that?

For reference I have copy pasted the code I use to hide the columns in the first place. I am guessing I will need to find a way to delete the columns instead. The problem with that is that if I do Columns(I).delete, the loop ends after deleting the first column.

Note: The counta in the code yields 17 columns. I have changed some of the naming and number of columns I am checking in the if condition in the interest of confidentiality. If there is any other info you need please let me know

**Edit: Upon further investigation and YowE3K's comment the problem in the code is that it is skipping the processing of a given column after one is deleted (because it is now in column i which the code thinks it has already processed)**

```
Sub NewView()
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Range("A14:Z14").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Temp_View"
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp_View").Activate
Worksheets("Temp_View").Range("B1").Formula = "=COUNTA($8:$8)"
ActiveSheet.Range("B8").PasteSpecial _
Paste:=xlPasteValues
Dim countUsedCols As Long
countUsedCols = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Temp View").Range("B1").Value
Dim currentColName As String
Dim newColName As String

For i = 2 To countUsedCols + 1


    currentColName = ActiveSheet.Cells(8, i).Value

    If currentColName <> "Salary" and currentColName<>"Net Worth" Then
        ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Select
        Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        'Selection.EntireColumn.Delete
```

Comment: Could you insert the headers in the VBA code?  i.e. each time you **don't** hide a column take the next header (from wherever you have them stored) and put it into the appropriate row of the column you are processing.  (That will be a lot easier to do if you create some `Worksheet` variables and `Set` each of those variables to the worksheets you are using - e.g. `Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet` at the start, then `Set wsTempView = ActiveSheet` after you have added a new sheet, and `Set wsHeaders = Worksheets("Headers")` to point to the header sheet.)

Comment: I can't see why deleting a column would cause your code to end after the deletion.  I **can** see that it would (depending on what other code you have that hasn't been pasted into the question) skip the processing of the column after the one you delete (because it is now in column `i` which your code thinks it has already processed) - but that is a quite different issue to just stopping processing altogether.

Comment: Upon further investigation, it seems what you said is happening. I had interpreted the problem incorrectly.  What would you suggest as a fix? I am not aware of a condition that allows me to track if a column was deleted or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best way loop over columns or rows (if you are going to delete some of them) is going backwards:

```
For i = countUsedCols To 2 Step -1

currentColName = ActiveSheet.Cells(8, i).Value

If currentColName <> "Salary" And currentColName <> "Net Worth" Then
    ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Delete
End If
```

That way you dont have to mess with you variables or to worry about the effexcts of the deleted cells. 
In Addition: you need'nt select the column before deleting.

Comment: Thanks. That's a more elegant solution than mine

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer to the issue ended up as follows:

```
For i = 2 To countUsedCols

currentColName = ActiveSheet.Cells(8, i).Value

If currentColName <> "Salary" and currentColName<>"Net Worth" Then
    ActiveSheet.Columns(i).Select
    'Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Selection.EntireColumn.Delete
    i = i - 1
    If currentColName = "" Then
       Exit for
    End if
....
End if
```

It was oddly simple